# Read delimiter separated text file using Spark SQL / Java API - Any direct methods?

Tags: java, apache-spark, java-8, apache-spark-sql

I am trying to read the delimiter separated text file using Spark SQL not using Spark Core.

Currently i am converting text file to JavaRDD first  using Spark Core API then converting that JavaRDD to DataFrame using sqlContext.

I have the text file schema in a separate file.

There are methods available in Spark SQL to read json and parquet directly.

```
sqlContext.read().json()
sqlContext.read().parquet()
```

Also, i can see one more method.

```
sqlContext.read().format("")
```

If i wanted to use `sqlContext.read().format("")` for reading text file what i have to pass inside `format()` method?

Is there anyway can we read text file directly without converting text file as JavaRDD.